# Identity Server 3 integration with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, identityserver3

Canb anyone provide documentation or a high level approach for using identity server 3 with on-premise SharePoint 2013.

Currently windows active directory is integrated with SharePoint and basic FBA (form based authentication) is being used.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 natively supports claims based authentication via WS-Federation but not via OpenID Connect. This is typically used within the enterprise for federated authentication from ADFS into SharePoint.

IdentityServer 2 does support WS-Fed, whereas IdentityServer 3 does not straight out of the box. There is a WS-Fed plugin however - this should be considered option #1.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.WsFederation

Another option might be to wire up ADFS v3 between IdentityServer3 and SharePoint.

As a third alternative, I've set up our IdentityServer v2 instance as an IDP for SharePoint for a few customers - it's a pretty easy process following the Microsoft recipe, replacing the word "ADFS" for "IdSvr2" :)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396